# Is it possible to dodge/block a bullet with perfect reaction time?

Tags: humans

As the title states, would it be possible to dodge or block a bullet with perfect reaction time? By perfect, I mean that the person views the world like a slow motion video at 100,000 fps, but can only move at the speed of a normal person.

The character in question is standing like a boxer would with both his arms raised. His hands are covered in unobtanium gloves which will let him deflect the bullets but he cannot block them straight on.

He is capable of reacting before the bullet leaves the gun because he can see the trigger being pulled  and any firing mechanisms (that are visible) moving before the bullet actually exits the barrel of the gun.

The shooter is roughly 20 meters away and is using a M16.

Comment: Also this one https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/77686/30492

Comment: @L.Dutch I guess the dupe is close enough to be believable (well in a lot of anime its already believable). Still though, would a squishy human arm be able to move that distance fast enough? It would need to move a couple of cm in 0.02 seconds....

Comment: play [superhot](https://superhotgame.com/) ... it will be fine

Comment: No it is not. Consider he following thought experiment: There is  maximum speed you can move your hand in an arc.  Do that firing a gun and the bullets will spray along the same angle of arc, in the same time.  Get 20m away and the bullets are hitting along a circumference far faster than than a human arm can move along that circumference.  Therefore no hand moving at maximum human speed can block bullets in all scenarios, regardless of reaction time.  However, you might be able to block a single shot if you have a suite of superhuman senses AND the shooter is unaware of your skills.

Comment: @Mark_Anderson Thats why I said his hands were already raised. Since everything is in slow motion to him, he can move his hands to where the barrel of the gun is facing before it is shot. He might be able to block 2 shots (1 for each hand) but after that it would have to depend on the spray. Keep in mind the inaccuracy caused by recoil won't be a problem, since he should be able to track the movement of the barrel and see the exact trajectory of each bullet. Its just the pure number of bullets and their distribution which will matter.

Comment: @Jannis Superhot looks pretty good, but isn't it a classic case of being able to move faster than possible. The person in this case isn't invincible... his power is a living hell for him, since he views everything in 100,000 fps... which makes him death and mute (like imagine trying to talk in slow motion)

Comment: @Shadowzee -- The starting position of the hands helps, but it doesn't change the fundamental maths.  Standing 20 feet away, the shooter can move the target point faster than the maximum speed of a human hand. Therefore you can't keep the hands in blocking locations, and you certainly can't move the hands into place to block in the time it takes to pull the trigger and the bullet to get to you. ie. Perfect senses and magic gloves can't make you bulletproof.  You could block some non-automatic fire from a larger distance MAYBE, but you are not guaranteed to make blocks under all scenarios.