# Dodging bullets

Tags: science-based, humans, super-powers, anatomy, firearms

We all know dodging bullets is impossible  but how bout a person with super vision or just decent vision, seeing exactly when the person pulling the trigger predicts where the bullets gonna go and changes direction. how fast would this persons perception need to be.  A trained officer can pull a trigger in 1.71 seconds and a untrained person more than that. does this give the said person ample time to move away / get closer? Edit since links are impossible here for some reason  the study i linked was using a standard officer uses a glock pistol.  And the timing is  was used to when an officer can pull recongnize a threat  and pull the trigger.  Since many of you need to specify  the distance lets give it the max range a glock 18 can fire while still being effective 55 yards . Can a person with super vision see the cop pulling the trigger and effectivily dodge the bullet by predicting where the bullet will go.

Comment: Related or even duplicate: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/77686/30492

Comment: That apart: firing a gun is not an exact science, and fired bullet have a dispersion around a point. Moreover, what is this supervision? what does it entail?

Comment: in my opinion even if you can see it before firing you still need a good reflects

Comment: [*Equilibrium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilibrium_(film)) (2002), a film by Kurt Wimmer, with Christian Bale, Emily Watson, and Taye Diggs. Features extended [gun kata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_fu) sequences.

Comment: You really need to specify what the conditions are.  Is the shooter firing a rifle or a pistol?  How far away?  Can you see the shooter, or is s/he firing from cover?  Two points, FWIW: 1) From my own experience, it's possible to see some bullets - shotguns and .22 shorts, at least - in flight, if you're standing behind and slightly to the side of the shooter.  2) With a nearby shooter, you're not dodging the bullet, you're getting away from where the muzzle is pointed - that is, can you move out of the way faster than the shooter can react?

Comment: You can use links here with [markedown](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) formatting. At the moment your question is a wall of text, difficult to read, can you edit it to be more user-friendly? Unfortunatley, even with the edit it will be off-topic because you've given us no worldbuilding context and it seems to be about a single character's story (as you will see that the post of which it is a duplicate is also closed as off-topic). (From review)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Forget it**

Mythbusters did an exhaustive treatment of this question in [episode 167](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Q03sDQRxoY).  The short version - even if you know exactly where the round is going to go, there is insufficient time between observing that the round has been fired and the round arriving to get out of the way, even out to 400 yards.  At 500 yards there was barely time to get out of the way, but normal human eyesight was insufficient to even see the muzzle flash without using a "Hollywood blank" with an unrealistically large flash.

Note that this test assumed that the target knew exactly where the round would go.  In real life:

- no one knows exactly when the trigger will "break" and the round will be fired (I am curious about the source of the "trained officer can pull a trigger in 1.71 seconds" assertion); and
- no one knows exactly where the barrel will be pointing at the moment the trigger breaks;
- no one knows exactly where the round will go until it gets there.  (Competition shooting would not be an event if the results could be predicted in advance!)

Other variables - such as the type of ammunition being fired and consistency from one round to the next - would be practically impossible for an external observer to have knowledge of.

As a result of all this uncertainty, unless a person is truly prescient they cannot dodge bullets.  Soldiers can and do attempt to move unpredictably, exposing themselves so briefly that an aimed shot cannot be taken.  At melee ranges a person can and should try to move out of line with the barrel of an opponent's firearm and/or knock the barrel out of line if they do not wish to be shot.  Unfortunately, that is as good as it gets for those in the line of fire.